# How to deploy AWS elasticsearch using serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, serverless-framework

I need to use AWS elasticsearch service but also want to automate it. We have serverless configuration. How can we create an AWS elasticsearch service using serverless.yml?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can add CloudFormation resources to the "resources" section. For ElasticSearch this would look something like this.

```
service: aws-nodejs
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    environment:
      elasticURL:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ ElasticSearchInstance , DomainEndpoint ]

resources:
  Resources:
    ElasticSearchInstance:
      Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
      Properties:
        EBSOptions:
          EBSEnabled: true
          VolumeType: gp2
          VolumeSize: 10
        ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
          InstanceType: t2.small.elasticsearch
          InstanceCount: 1
          DedicatedMasterEnabled: false
          ZoneAwarenessEnabled: false
        ElasticsearchVersion: 5.3
```

Comment: Perfect. That's what I needed. Thanks :-)

Comment: How does this work with the Access Policy? Can we dynamically reference the lambda function role?

Comment: This works perfectly and created a elastic search instance, but how can i create the elastic search client and use it to insert/fetch data inside my handler?

Comment: I used a similar approach, but i've followed the example from serverless' GitHub. Might be helpful for someone else https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-golang-dynamo-stream-to-elasticsearch/serverless.yml

Answer (score 4):

to add to Jens' answer, you might want the output

you can add this to your `serverless.yml` config

```
Outputs:
  DomainArn:
    Value: !GetAtt ElasticsearchDomain.DomainArn
  DomainEndpoint:
    Value: !GetAtt ElasticsearchDomain.DomainEndpoint
  SecurityGroupId:
    Value: !Ref mySecurityGroup
  SubnetId:
    Value: !Ref subnet
```

Comment: I’m lost on this Ref to mySecurityGroup, where would I need to configure that?